# What is this floating icon?

Tags: macos, mojave, icon

[image]

Can anyone tell me what this floating icon is? it appears in front of all windows. It can be moved about, but nothing happens if I right click on it. I'm running Mojave.

How to get rid of it? What is it?

A small person made this happen and they can't remember what buttons they clicked...

Comment: Much love to the smol ones, they are clever and inquisitive beyond belief. It’s the wrong shape for a dictation overlay - https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-dictation-mh40584/mac

Comment: This is "pine-decoration" emoji from apple emoji pack as far as I can tell

Comment: Does it come back after a restart?

Comment: Yep persists restarts...